# Ubuntu 17.10 freezes after login

Tags: lenovo, freeze, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

it freezes completely without possibility of use ctrl + alt + F{n} keys.

in some answer on this website i read people talk about the kernel, the cstate=1 on grub config, the proprietary driver problem and that problems on ubuntu are related to Ubuntu-[Lenovo notebook] combination that doesn't works.

Noone talks about DE.

if someone has the solution please told me, because using LXDE or I3 or MATE or anything equals to GNOME or UBUNTU(also in xorg) works without problem.

at this time i am using i3 but i prefer use the default DE.

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the reason is that 17.10 is unstable instead they told don't. it has problem w/lenovo laptops.
Problem solved in the 18.04 Ubuntu version